# Keras-tuning can't find callback

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, keras-tuner

I am using keras-tuner in order to obtain the best set of hyperparameters for my model.
I can reproduce my problem for a random dataset:

```
def generate_data(n_windows, n_timesteps):
    feature_vector_list = []
    label_list = []
    for i in range(10):
        x = tf.random.normal((n_windows, n_timesteps))
        feature_vector = [x]
        choices = [np.array([1, 0]), np.array([0, 1]),
                   np.array([0, 0]), np.array([1,1])]
        labels = np.array([random.choice(choices) for i in range(n_windows)])
        feature_vector_list.append(feature_vector)
        label_list.append(labels)
    return feature_vector_list, label_list


def custom_generator(feat_vector_list, label_list):
    assert len(feat_vector_list) == len(label_list), \
        "Number of feature vectors inconsistent with the number of labels"
    counter = 0
    while True:
        feat_vec = feat_vector_list[counter]
        list_labels = label_list[counter]
        counter = (counter + 1) % len(feat_vector_list)
        yield feat_vec, list_labels
```

Here is the model:

```
def model_builder(hp):

    n_timesteps, n_features, n_outputs = 60, 1, 2

    hp_units = hp.Int("units", min_value=50, max_value=500, step=50)
    hp_filters = hp.Int("filters", 4, 32, step=4, default=8)
    hp_kernel_size = hp.Int("kernel_size", 3, 50, step=1)
    hp_pool_size = hp.Int("pool_size", 2, 8, step=1)
    hp_dropout = hp.Float("dropout", 0.1, 0.5, step=0.1)

    input1 = Input(shape=(n_timesteps, n_features))
    conv1 = Conv1D(filters=hp_filters,
                   kernel_size=hp_kernel_size,
                   activation='relu')(input1)
    drop1 = Dropout(hp_dropout)(conv1)
    if hp.Choice("pooling", ["max", "avg"]) == "max":
        pool1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=hp_pool_size)(drop1)
    else:
        pool1 = AveragePooling1D(pool_size=hp_pool_size)(drop1)
    flatten1 = Flatten()(pool1)
    # hidden layers
    dense1 = Dense(hp_units, activation='relu')(flatten1)
    outputs = Dense(n_outputs, activation='softmax')(dense1)
    model = Model(inputs=[input1, input2], outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp.Float("learning_rate",
                                                                            0.01,
                                                                            0.1,
                                                                            step=0.2)),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

Here is the training script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x_train, y_train = generate_data(350, 60)
    x_val, y_val = generate_data(80, 60)
    training_generator = custom_generator(x_train, y_train)
    validation_generator = custom_generator(x_val, y_val)
    tuner = kt.Hyperband(
        model_builder,
        objective="val_accuracy",
        max_epochs=70,
        factor=3,
        directory="Results",
        project_name="cnn_tunning"
    )
    stop_early = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',
                                                  patience=5,
                                                  min_delta=0.002)

    tuner.search(
        training_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=N_WINDOWS,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=75,
        callbacks=[stop_early],
    )
```

Now what I have found is that after the hyperband starts using a decent number of iterations and the callback I set up should come into play I get this error:

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1733] INVALID_ARGUMENT: ValueError: Could not find callback with key=pyfunc_530 in the registry.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/diogomota/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/WUAle-Z1-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 259, in __call__
    raise ValueError(f"Could not find callback with key={token} in the "

ValueError: Could not find callback with key=pyfunc_530 in the registry.


W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:107] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: INVALID_ARGUMENT: ValueError: Could not find callback with key=pyfunc_530 in the registry.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/diogomota/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/WUAle-Z1-py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py", line 259, in __call__
    raise ValueError(f"Could not find callback with key={token} in the "

ValueError: Could not find callback with key=pyfunc_530 in the registry.
```

However it just proceeds to the next trial so I'm not sure what is going on, can someone explain why it can't find the callback?

I'm using `tensorflow 2.8` and `keras-tuner 1.1.2`

I could only find one place online with a similar issue, but no solution provided: https://issuemode.com/issues/tensorflow/tensorflow/72982126

**EDIT**:

1. Provided full error message
2. After further debugging, the problem comes solely from using a generator as input for the `.search()`. I do not know the reason for this being an issue. Regular training using the `.fit()` works without any issues
3. Added dataset generation code for reproducibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.8/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py#L259) of the error, and reviewing the [similar error](https://issuemode.com/issues/tensorflow/tensorflow/72982126) provided, it looks like this issue is not due to the actual model callback (`tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStoppingCallback`). The error occurs in the `FuncRegistry` class, which is a helper that maintains a map of unique tokens to registered python functions, and it looks like in both cases, the token (`pyfunc_XXX`) does not map to a function. Functions are inserted [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.8/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py#L348) when `_internal_py_func` is called, while wrapping of a Python function (to be executed as an eager Tensorflow operation) or while computing the gradient of an eager function. The global registry of tokens to functions (the `FuncRegistry` object) is supplied to `initialize_py_trampoline`, which is bound to the `InitializePyTrampoline` function in C++ through PyBind, so the reference of token to function maps is maintained in the C++ runtime as well.

At that level, tracing the error to [C++ source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.8/tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc#L108) from the logs, it's occurring in the destructor of the inner class `Iterator`, a field of `GeneratorDatasetOp`. The destructor is called when the object is out of scope or explicitly deleted - meaning it would be called when the generator is finished it's task, which sounds like it may be consistent with the observations you were making with when the error occurred.

In summary, without being able to probe much further without a dataset, it sounds like there may be a problem with the custom generator. I would recommend trying to perform the training without `keras-tuner` and the same generator implementation, to identify if the problem is consistent with other observation linked, as they were not using `keras-tuner` but they were using a custom generator. If the error persists, it would also be worth evaluating if previous releases (e.g; Tensorflow 2.7 or below) has the same problem with the generator. If it's consistently failing, it may warrant submitting an actual issue to the Tensorflow Github repository, as it may actually be a core bug which requires further exploration.

Also, if you don't need to use a generator (as in, the data can fit into memory), I would recommend trying to supply the dataset directly (calling `fit` with a list of numpy arrays or a numpy array instead of supplying generator functions), as that path won't touch the `DatasetGenerator` code which is currently failing, and that should not affect your hyperparameter search.

## Update

Thank you for the additional information and including code to replicate your generator functions. I was able to reproduce the issue in Python 3.7/Tensorflow 2.8/keras-tuner 1.1.2 on CPU. If you inspect the `_funcs` (the  field in the global registry which maintains a dictionary of tokens to weak references to functions), it's actually empty. Upon further inspection, it looks like every time a new trial is started, `_funcs` is cleared and repopulated, which is consistent if keras-tuner is creating a new graph (model) every time (although the same registry `FuncRegistry` is used throughout).

The error does not occur if the `EarlyStopping` callback is omitted, so you were correct to say the error is linked to the callback. It also appears the error is non-deterministic, as the trial and epoch of the occurrence varies per run.

With the cause of the error narrowed down, another person experienced  [the same issue](https://www.reddit.com/r/tensorflow/comments/scd0d6/strange_behavior_of_min_delta_in_earlystopping/), and their observations were the cause of the error being related to explicitly setting the `min_delta` parameter in the callback, as you are doing as well, which no other `keras-tuner` example does (e.g; in this [example](https://keras.io/guides/keras_tuner/distributed_tuning/) and this [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/keras_tuner) from the documentation, they only have `monitor` and/or `patience` set).

The impact of setting `min_delta` in the `EarlyStopping` callback, which is set to 0 by default, can be seen [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.8.0/keras/callbacks.py#L1744-L1891). Specifically, `_is_improvement` can evaluate to True less frequently when `min_delta` is set to some non-zero value:

```
    if self._is_improvement(current, self.best):
      self.best = current
      self.best_epoch = epoch
      if self.restore_best_weights:
        self.best_weights = self.model.get_weights()
      # Only restart wait if we beat both the baseline and our previous best.
      if self.baseline is None or self._is_improvement(current, self.baseline):
        self.wait = 0

  def _is_improvement(self, monitor_value, reference_value):
    return self.monitor_op(monitor_value - self.min_delta, reference_value)
```

Note that in your case, `self.monitor_op` is `np.less`, since the metric you're monitoring is `val_loss`:

```
      if (self.monitor.endswith('acc') or self.monitor.endswith('accuracy') or
          self.monitor.endswith('auc')):
        self.monitor_op = np.greater
      else:
        self.monitor_op = np.less
```

When `self._is_improvement` is evaluated less frequently, the `patience` criterion (`self.wait >= self.patience`) will be met more often, since `self.wait` will reset less frequently (as `self.baseline` is None by default):

```
if self.wait >= self.patience and epoch > 0:
      self.stopped_epoch = epoch
      self.model.stop_training = True
      if self.restore_best_weights and self.best_weights is not None:
        if self.verbose > 0:
          io_utils.print_msg(
              'Restoring model weights from the end of the best epoch: '
              f'{self.best_epoch + 1}.')
        self.model.set_weights(self.best_weights)
```

With this narrowed down, it appears to have something to do with the model stopping training more frequently, and references to operations in the graph not existing anymore when `keras-tuner` is running a trial.

In simpler terms, it seems like a bug in `keras-tuner` that needs to be submitted, which I did [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/issues/688) with all the details from this response. For purposes of proceeding in the meantime, if the `min_delta` criteria isn't necessary, I would suggest removing that parameter from `EarlyStopping` and running the script again to see if you still hit the issue.

## Update 2

Thank you for the additional information. I was able to reproduce the successful run if the generator is not used, and it also looks like the [other case I referenced](https://www.reddit.com/r/tensorflow/comments/scd0d6/strange_behavior_of_min_delta_in_earlystopping/) was also using a generator in conjunction with `EarlyStopping` with a `min_delta` supplied.

Upon some further inspection, the function which is not found in the registry is `finalize_py_func`, as in every token which causes that error maps to `finalize_py_func` before `_funcs` is cleared. `finalize_py_func` is the [inner function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.8/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L1100) wrapped by `script_ops.numpy_function`, which [wraps a python function to be used as Tensorflow op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.8/tensorflow/python/ops/script_ops.py#L684). The function where `finalize_py_func` is defined and returned as Tensorflow op, `finalize_fn`, is supplied when constructing a generator, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.8/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L1120). Looking at the documentation of the finalize function in the generator [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.8/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L4555), it says "A TensorFlow function that will be called on the result of init_func` immediately before a C++ iterator over this dataset is destroyed.".

**Overall, the error is related to the generator, not the min_delta parameter**. While setting the `min_delta` expedites how quickly the error occurs, it can happen even if the `min_delta` is omitted if the `patience` is lowered enough to force the early stopping callback to trigger more frequently. Using your example, if you set `patience` to 1 and remove `min_delta`, the error appears pretty quickly.

I have revised the [github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-tuner/issues/688) to include that detail. It looks like the error still exists in Tensorflow 2.7, but if you downgrade to Tensorflow 2.6 (and Keras 2.6), the error does not occur. If downgrading is possible, that may be the best option for proceeding until the issue is addressed.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, I think the issue is between the generator and keras-tuner as regular training works without an issue. Can you have a look again now that I added important details to the question?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I still have the issue even without the min_delta parameter, if I don't use generators I can have the callback with the min_delta and it searches without any errors, so it seems that the issue is with the callback and the generator, maybe not just the min_delta parameter

Comment: Thank you for the information - I added another update with some further details. I think it's a bug introduced in Tensorflow 2.7+ causing this issue, and unfortunately I don't know if there's an immediate solution besides downgrading to 2.6, converting your training to not use the generator functions, or omitting the callback.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation and for raising the issue!

Comment: Sure thing! I wish I could help more, but hopefully this information will enable you to move forward with your project. I'll post another update if the github issue gets a response.