# Keras tuner Bayesian Optmization graph error

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, bayesian, keras-tuner

I am trying to optimize a convolutional neural network with Bayesian Optimization algorithm provided in keras tuner library.

When I perform the line: `tuner_cnn.search(datagen.flow(X_trainRusReshaped,Y_trainRusHot), epochs=50, batch_size=256)`
I encounter this error:
`InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error`

One-Hot-Encode y_train and y_test as the following:

```
y_train = to_categorical(y_train)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test)

X_trainShape = X_train.shape[1]*X_train.shape[2]*X_train.shape[3]
X_testShape = X_test.shape[1]*X_test.shape[2]*X_test.shape[3]
X_trainFlat = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], X_trainShape)
X_testFlat = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], X_testShape)
# One-hot-encoding
Y_trainRusHot = to_categorical(Y_trainRus, num_classes = 2)
Y_testRusHot = to_categorical(Y_testRus, num_classes = 2)
```

I defined my model builder like that:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=180,
    horizontal_flip=True,vertical_flip = True)

def model_builder(hp):
  model = Sequential()
  #model.add(Input(shape=(50,50,3)))
  for i in range(hp.Int('num_blocks', 1, 2)):
    hp_padding=hp.Choice('padding_'+ str(i), values=['valid', 'same'])
    hp_filters=hp.Choice('filters_'+ str(i), values=[32, 64])

    model.add(Conv2D(hp_filters, (3, 3), padding=hp_padding, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', input_shape=(50, 50, 3)))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
    model.add(Dropout(hp.Choice('dropout_'+ str(i), values=[0.0, 0.1, 0.2])))
    model.add(Flatten())

    hp_units = hp.Int('units', min_value=25, max_value=150, step=25)
    model.add(Dense(hp_units, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
    model.add(Dense(10,activation="softmax"))
    hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3])
    hp_optimizer=hp.Choice('Optimizer', values=['Adam', 'SGD'])

    if hp_optimizer == 'Adam':
      hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3])

    elif hp_optimizer == 'SGD':
      hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice('learning_rate', values=[1e-2, 1e-3])
      nesterov=True
      momentum=0.9

    model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate), metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

perform the tuner search:

```
tuner_cnn = kt.tuners.BayesianOptimization(
    model_builder,
    objective='val_loss',
    max_trials=100,
    directory='.',
    project_name='tuning-cnn')

tuner_cnn.search(datagen.flow(X_trainRusReshaped,Y_trainRusHot), epochs=50, batch_size=256)
```

I also tried to do:

```
tuner_cnn.search(X_trainRusReshaped, Y_trainRusHot, epochs=80, validation_data=(X_testRusReshaped, Y_testRusHot), callbacks=[stop_early])
```

But it does not work neither. Any idea?

Comment: Whats the full error message? Does a regular fit call work?

Comment: On the last line I have this error: `ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-89d6ff2279c0> in <module>()
----> 1 tuner_cnn.search(X_trainRusReshaped, Y_trainRusHot, epochs=80, validation_data=(X_testRusReshaped, Y_testRusHot), callbacks=[stop_early])`  and `ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 10) vs (None, 2)).`

Comment: yes a regular fit call works: `H = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X,Y,batch_size=256),steps_per_epoch=len(X_trainRusReshaped) / batch_size,epochs=epochs,validation_data=(X_testRusReshaped, Y_testRusHot),callbacks=[early_stopping_monitor])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the full error message I was able to narrow down where the issue is coming from. The issue is that your last `Dense` layer has `10 units`, which means you expect `10 classes` (you even chose the correct activation function given the number of `units`). However you have `Binary CrossEntropy` as **loss**.

So you either have `10 classes` and use either `categorical` or `sparse categorical CrossEntropy` or you have `2 classes` and so the loss is indeed `Binary CrossEntropy`.

Comment: You are totally right. numclass=2, I don't know why I put 10. So the line: `tuner_cnn.search(X_trainRusReshaped, Y_trainRusHot, epochs=80, validation_data=(X_testRusReshaped, Y_testRusHot), callbacks=[stop_early])` works without any errors. I just have a question the datagen cannot be applied inside the `tuner_cnn.search` ?

Comment: Well, theoretically you should be able to pass generators to the search method without a problem. However, when I did it, by chance I (and the stack overflow user that helped me) ended up finding a bug on keras tuner code which is explained in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72145506/keras-tuning-cant-find-callback. So if you have a similar issue, rest assured it is not your fault.